# AutoHotkey: Search for 3 specific characters then trim 8 characters from right for each valid instance in that column

Tags: string, replace, autohotkey, trim

My apologies if i have not been able to explain this in easy terms.

What i have is: 
A syslistview to get data from. Column1 data needs to be modified.

What we know is: 
the 3 characters we are looking for will always be the rightmost of text in  column1, if they are present at all.(Those 3 characters are "FUT")

What is needed is: 
If "FUT" is found in column1 row1, then TRIM 8 characters from right. (includes trimming off of "FUT" as well). Then move down and repeat till last value of that column.

Below is the code developed by me till now. Need help in removing "xxxxxFUT" if "FUT" found :

```
 #Persistent
 #Include %A_ScriptDir%
 #SingleInstance force
 #NoEnv
 SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
 SetTitleMatchMode, 1
 SetKeyDelay, 150, 150, Play
 SetControlDelay,0
 iffut:="FUT"
 SetTimer,datos,10
 return

 datos:
 IfWinExist,DataTable ahk_class #32770
  {
    WinGetTitle,winname,DataTable   
    StringTrimLeft,winname,winname,11
    IfInString,winname,%iffut%
      {
        StringTrimRight,winname,winname,8
      }

    ControlGet,dato,List,,SysListView321,DataTable

    StringReplace, dato, dato, %A_Tab%, `,, All   
    StringReplace, dato, dato, %A_Space%, `,, All 
    IfInString,dato,%iffut%
      {
        ;MsgBox,there
         StringReplace, dato, dato, .{5}FUT, , All
      }

    FormatTime, mydttm, , ddMMyy_HHmmss
    FileAppend,%dato%,%winname%_%mydttm%.txt

    return
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

A better answer is

```
  dato := RegExReplace(dato, ".{5}FUT", "").
```

No need to check if it is in the string, as it will do nothing if it isn't. – Provided by --> Elliot DeNolf

---

Got an answer somewhere else so posting it here as well.

String-pattern is created and then using regexreplace to remove all such strings.

Below is the code to achieve that:

```
 regex_patten = \d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}FUT

 if RegExMatch(string, regex_patten)
 newstring := RegExReplace(string, regex_patten, "")

 msgbox % "old string:`n`n" string "`n`nnew string`n`n" newstring
```

Comment: No need to do a `RegExMatch` as the `RegExReplace` will check for the pattern and then replace if it exists. One-liner `newString := RegExMatch(string, "\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}FUT", "")`.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance I'd use Regular Expressions to [match](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm) "FUT" and than [SubStr()](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Functions.htm) to trim out the 8 characters.

Below is an example of such:

```
var = any amount of data can be here and xxxxxFUT as you can see FUT is removed!
; ~= is shorthand for RegExMatach 
MsgBox % SubStr(var, 1, (var ~= "FUT") - 6) SubStr(var, (var ~= "FUT") + 3)
```

Edit: Code was edited above to better reflect your problem, since you expanded upon it.

Now to apply this to your code:

```
 #Persistent
 #Include %A_ScriptDir%
 #SingleInstance force
 #NoEnv
 SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
 SetTitleMatchMode, 1
 SetKeyDelay, 150, 150, Play
 SetControlDelay,0
 iffut:="FUT"
 SetTimer,datos,10
 return

 datos:
 IfWinExist,DataTable ahk_class #32770
  {
    WinGetTitle,winname,DataTable   
    StringTrimLeft,winname,winname,11
    IfInString,winname,%iffut%
      {
        StringTrimRight,winname,winname,8
      }

    ControlGet,dato,List,,SysListView321,DataTable

    StringReplace, dato, dato, %A_Tab%, `,, All   
    StringReplace, dato, dato, %A_Space%, `,, All 
    Loop, parse, dato, `n, `r 
    {
        IfInString, A_LoopField, %iffut%
            Results .= SubStr(A_LoopField, 1, (A_LoopField ~= "FUT") - 6) SubStr(A_LoopField, (A_LoopField ~= "FUT") + 3) "`n"
        Else 
            Results .= A_LoopField "`n"
    }
    FormatTime, mydttm, , ddMMyy_HHmmss
    FileAppend,%Results%,%winname%_%mydttm%.txt

    return
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, ahkcoder. This code modified only the 1st cell (Column1 Row1). Rest of the flle was not modified at all. Could you pls be kind enough to inform also on how a loop can be created so that all values of 1st column get modified.

Comment: thanks for helping, AhkCoder. I will try the approach you provided. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

`RegExReplace` is the quickest and easiest way:

```
str := "before15NOVFUTsomeotherstring"
newStr := RegExReplace(str, ".{5}FUT", "")
msgbox % newStr
```

The pattern matches "FUT" along with any 5 characters following and replaces them with a blank string. If not found, it does nothing.

Comment: You are trying to use a RegEx pattern with `StringReplace` which is not possible. Use [RegExReplace](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/RegExReplace.htm)

Comment: `dato := RegExReplace(dato, ".{5}FUT", "")`. No need to check if it is in the string, as it will do nothing if it isn't.